# react native update flat list from another screen

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-native-flatlist

Is there any method  to update Flat List or re-render it from another screen 
i have screen A and B 
in  A i fetch the data from API 
in B i add more data

my problem is the data i add it dose not appear until exit the app and re open it

in screen A i have the flat list

```
   componentWillMount(){

          AsyncStorage.getItem('customer_id').then((customer_id) => {

        AsyncStorage.getItem('sale_id').then((sale_id) => {

            this.props.get_notes(sale_id,customer_id)   

    });

       });

   }


      <FlatList
                   style={{flex:1}}
                   data={this.props.data}
                   renderItem={this._renderListID}
                   keyExtractor={item => item.note_id}
             />
```

Comment: Did you using Redux?

Comment: yes i use Redux 

const mapStateToProps = state => {
    return {
      error: state.add_notes.error,
      loading: state.add_notes.loading,
      data: state.add_notes.data
    }
  }
  
  export default connect(mapStateToProps, { add_notes ,get_notes})(AddImage);

Comment: did you check with extra data, extraData={this.props.data}

Comment: @JebinBenny i try it like this 

  <FlatList
extraData={this.props.data}
                   style={{flex:1}}
                   data={this.props.data}
                   renderItem={this._renderListID}
                   keyExtractor={item => item.note_id}
             />
not working